# Joomla function to list down models in 3.11 not working in Joomla 4

Tags: joomla-3.x

am calling file - getbrand.php to display list of models using ajax

default.php

```
<?php
function brand_down(){
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $sql = "SELECT * from #__car_categories where state='1'";
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    $list="";
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $list.="<option value='".$row->id."' style='padding-left:10px;'>".$row->cat_name."</option>";
    }
    return $list;
}

function model_down(){
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $sql = "SELECT * from #__car_products where state='1'";
    $db->setQuery($sql);
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    $list="";
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $list.="<option value='".$row->id."' style='padding-left:10px;'>".$row->prod_name."</option>";
    }
    return $list;
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ajax.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript">
 function showModelCar(str)
 {
    url = "getbrand.php?s="+str;
    getRequest(url,"txtHint");
 }
</script>
```

getbrand.php

```
    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));  
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );
    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
    
     // GET using JInput
    $jinput  = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
    $ModelId = $jinput->get('s', '', 'INT');
    
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();   
    $query = $db->getQuery(true);
    
    
$query->select($db->qn(array('id','prod_id','prod_name')))
  ->from($db->qn('#__car_products'))
  ->where($db->qn('state') . ' = 1')
  ->where($db->qn('prod_id') . ' = ' . (int)$ModelId)
  $db->setQuery($query);    
$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
$list='<select name="model" class="list-box" id="model"  lang="" title="Model">';
$list.='<option value="" style="padding-left:10px;" selected>-Select Model-</option>';
foreach($rows as $row){
    $list.='<option value="'.$row->id .'" style="padding-left:10px;">'.$row->prod_name.'</option>';
}
$list.='</select>';
   $list.='</select>';
    die($list);
?>
```

Although its working in joomla 3.10, but showing factory error in joomla 4 with.

```
> HTTP 500 Whoops, looks like something went wrong.
Failed to start application
Exception
Exception
in F:\wamp64\www\7thdecember2022\libraries\src\Factory.php (line 140)
     * @throws  \Exception     */    public static function getApplication()    {        if (!self::$application) {            throw new \Exception('Failed to start application', 500);        }        return self::$application;    }
Factory::getApplication('site')
in F:\wamp64\www\7thdecember2022\getbrand.php (line 6)
<?php    define( '_JEXEC', 1 );    define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));      require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/defines.php' );    require_once ( JPATH_BASE .'/includes/framework.php' );    $mainframe = JFactory::getApplication('site');
```

Any tips on how to make it work in joomla 4 too. Any suggestions

**Now new function in default.php**

default.php

```
    <?php
    function brand_down(){
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $sql = "SELECT * from #__car_categories where state='1'";
        $db->setQuery($sql);
        $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
        $list="";
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $list.="<option value='".$row->id."' style='padding-left:10px;'>".$row->cat_name."</option>";
        }
        return $list;
    }
    
    function model_down(){
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();
        $sql = "SELECT * from #__car_products where state='1'";
        $db->setQuery($sql);
        $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
        $list="";
        foreach($rows as $row){
            $list.="<option value='".$row->id."' style='padding-left:10px;'>".$row->prod_name."</option>";
        }
        return $list;
    }

function showModelCar{
        $db = JFactory::getDBO();   
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);            
    $query->select($db->qn(array('id','prod_id','prod_name')))
      ->from($db->qn('#__car_products'))
      ->where($db->qn('state') . ' = 1')
      ->where($db->qn('prod_id') . ' = ' . (int)$ModelId)
      $db->setQuery($query);    
    $rows = $db->loadObjectList();
    $list='<select name="model" class="list-box" id="model"  lang="" title="Model">';
    $list.='<option value="" style="padding-left:10px;" selected>-Select Model-</option>';
    foreach($rows as $row){
        $list.='<option value="'.$row->id .'" style="padding-left:10px;">'.$row->prod_name.'</option>';
    }
    $list.='</select>';
       $list.='</select>';
        die($list);
]
    ?>

and call in on same page

    <div class="search-box">
                          <div class="search-box-left">Brand *</div>
                        <div class="search-box-right">          
    
                    <select name="brand" class="list-box" id="brand"  lang="" title="Brand" onchange="showModelCar(this.value)" required>
                    <option value="" selected="selected" style='padding-left:10px;'>Select Make</option>
                    <?php echo brand_drop_down();?>
                    
    
                  </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="search-box-left">Model </div>
                        <div class="search-box-right">
                        <div id="txtHint">
                        <select name="model" class="list-box"  id="model"  lang="" title="Model">
                         <option value="" selected="selected" style="padding-left:10px;"> Select Model</option>
                         <?php //echo $this->model;?>
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        </div>
```

But seems its not working as earlier script was used and                             not getting executed now

Comment: Is this code part of an extension within Joomla or is it something external to a Joomla instance? You are getting the Site application but have the define & require statements that would not be required if you are within a Joomla extension.

Comment: Hi its saved as external php file saved underpublic_html to load product details. Like theres module of showing company and products. When Suzuki, Honda, VW as a company name when selected then through query model details are loaded under respective brands. Am updating the complete code

Comment: @Irata - Hi updated question with complete details. Pls guide if possible. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things work differently in Joomla 4 so you will need either a different copy of the code or check to determine which version of Joomla you are using and execute the right command.

In Joomla 4 `Factory::getApplication('site')` is no longer a valid statement as getApplication does not allow any parameters. In J4 you write it as `Factory::getApplication()` however that will just return you the current Application(eg. Site, Administrator,API,CLI) whereas your current use of getApplication('site') is saying you want the Site application.

That requires you to use the container to specify which application you want, `Factory::getContainer()->get(\Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::class);`

However I don't see anything in you piece of code that really needs anything from the Site so you could probably just use `Factory::getapplication()` and that would be enough to get the Input and for the rest of your code to do the data base query.

Comment: Thanks, but somehow getting Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\
ClassNotFoundError on Factory::getApplication() or Factory::getContainer()->get(\Joomla\CMS\Application\SiteApplication::class);

Comment: I think i should avoid calling external getbrand.php file and rather use function in main file default.php but somehow to my limited knowledge failing in same. Adding code in question as done

Comment: Your code looks like you are not following the Joomla MVC approach of keeping your data access(the Model) separate from your Display(the View) and you your example default.php has no Class or Use statements or the things I would expect to see that would help your extension work in Joomla. Maybe you are not trying to create an extension in Joomla, but if you are it might be better for you learn from some tutorials such as https://docs.joomla.org/J4.x:Developing_an_MVC_Component and/or https://blog.astrid-guenther.de/en/der-weg-zu-joomla4-erweiterungen/ that are written for Joomla 4.

Comment: Another useful reference is this online book that is a work in progress but I have found very useful, https://www.dionysopoulos.me/book.html

Comment: Sure, thanks will go through same for useful reference. Lastly is there a way to connect with you as i see you provide technical support.

Comment: I have updated my profile with contact details however if you are wanting to ask similar questions to what you have been already then it is better to ask them here on JSE so you can get more than just my thoughts and others might also learn from our exchanges.